# Add Jira Worklog comment using Soap in PHP

Tags: php, soap, jira

I am trying to add a comment to worklog in Jira using Soap service. If I comment out the first line this code adds a worklog with no comment.

```
$worklog['comment'] = 'this is a test comment';

$worklog['startDate'] = strtotime(date('d M y H:i:s', 
mktime( date("H", $TimeNow), 
    date("i", $TimeNow),
    date("s", $TimeNow), 
    date("n", $Date), 
    date("j", $Date),
    date("Y", $Date) )));

$worklog['timeSpent'] = $Time . "m";

$worklog = $connClient->addWorklogAndRetainRemainingEstimate($login, $issue->key, $worklog);
```

Any ideas on how to add comments to a worklog in Jira using Soap services and PHP will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you don't comment it out?

Comment: are you using zend framework???